# 'People living overseas' 'People who live overseas'

Tags: noun-phrases

In the two noun phrases, 'People living overseas' 'People who live overseas', is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: The first one has participial adj following it, and the second one has an adj. clause. That is the difference. As for meaning, I think both are same.

Comment: The first is not time dependent. *People living overseas could not travel directly to Melbourne last month*. The second phrase would need to be changed to suit the tense.

Comment: @Peter The second phrase need not be changed. "People who live overseas could not travel directly to Melbourne last month." sounds (and is) perfectly right.

Comment: @PatrickD, yes probably for that example, because it is very recent. What about "Before the Peace of Amiens men living in English ports needed to be able to avoid the press gangs"?